# Docker MongoDB authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, docker, connection-string

I am trying to setup a Mongo database with authentication inside a docker container. But no matter what I do I keep getting an error saying Authentication failed when I try to connect with my MongoDB.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4' 

services:
  catalogdb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: catalogdb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: CatalogDb
    ports:
    - "7000:27017"
    volumes:
    - mongo_data:/data/db 

  dnms.catalog.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dnmscatalogapi
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Catalog/DNMS.Catalog.API/Dockerfile
    container_name: dnms.catalog.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    depends_on:
      - catalogdb
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

When I open my container shell (`docker exec -it catalogdb /bin/bash`) and try to open the mongo shell (`mongo CatalogDb -u root -p secret`) it is giving me the authentication error.
When I try to connect to the database via my application with a connection string (`mongodb://root:secret@catalogdb:27017/CatalogDb?authSource=admin`) I get `Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.`. Connecting with MongoDB Compass (`mongodb://root:secret@localhost:7000/CatalogDb?authSource=admin`) also gives me an authentication failed error.

if I don't use authentication I can connect just fine, but I really want to secure my database. I've also tried adding a mongo init script with a volume mapping to docker-`entrypoint-initdb.d`, but I keep getting the same errors. What do I have to do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit if I specify the database where the user is supposed to be stored, i.e., mongo CatalogDb -u root -p secret --authenticationDatabase admin, I still get an authentication failed error

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the command 'mongo -u root -p secret --authenticationDatabase admin CatalogDb' also fails

Comment: And when you authenticate against `CatalogDb`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What do you mean? I am authenticating against CatalogDb

Comment: No, when you write `--authenticationDatabase admin` then you authenticate against `admin` database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ah right sorry, the command 'mongo -u root -p secret --authenticationDatabase CatalogDb' also fails

Comment: OK, then next question, did you create the user? I am not familiar with dockers.

Comment: @Jiren were you able to find a solution?